# Angular.js "controller as" Syntax suddenly stop working on Chrome v. 39.0.2171.95 m

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-scope

We're developing a WebApp on Angular.js v. 1.3 and Node.js v 10.2x and we use

```
 ng-controller="MainController as main"
```

and some others, but it's always the same Syntax. We have an initialization in the controller-script like

```
 this.theme='blue-grey';
```

In devtools we can see, that all variables (scopes) are not initialized and not present in the DOM at Appstart. After using them, e.g. with a

```
<select ng-model="main.theme"><option>Blue-Theme</option></select>
```

they are beeing processed by Angular.
In Summary: We use that Syntax strictly. (Worked till the last Chrome update!) AND we didn't have change the code! In Firefox everything is working fine. So maybe it's a Bug in Chrome ?!

Thanks and greetings from Germany

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use AngularJS Batarang (Chrome extension for AngularJS), try disable it and check your app again.
Batarang was updated a few days ago and some apps can be broken now, for example plnkr.co doesn't work for me anymore with enabled Batarang :(

Comment: Thanx hinok, that was exactly the problem. We decided to uninstall Batarang completely, because it has caused us several problems lately.

Comment: There is a new kid on the block called ng-inspector. It doesn't have all functionalities of Batarang but for simple displaying scopes works great (http://ng-inspector.org/)